# How can I show a multipage post as a single, wrapped post?

Tags: pagination

First up: this isn't the same as just showing a multipage post in full (that's done fairly trivially by using `<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); ?>`, FYI!).

What I want to do here is output HTML in my theme like this:

```
<div class="page-1">
    <!-- page one content goes here -->
</div>
<div class="page-2">
    <!-- page two content goes here -->
</div>
<!-- etc -->
```

I can't figure out a way to get the page's content that's grouped by `<!--nextpage-->` pagebreaks. I can get the raw post content (eg. before it's had `the_content` filter applied) and I suppose I could manually split the string by the pagebreak and perhaps then apply the filter to each page, but I'm wondering if there's a better way?

Comment: I think manually splitting is your only option.

Comment: Thanks – will post my code for this below in case it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like there's no existing way to do this, here's my solution. It just splits the content on the pagebreak tag, parses the HTML and wraps each page in a div:

```
function get_paginated_post($post) {
    $pagebreak = '<!--nextpage-->';
    $raw_post = $post->post_content;
    $pages = explode($pagebreak, $raw_post);
    $html = '';
    foreach ($pages as $p=>$page) {
        $html .= '<div class="page-' . ($p+1) . '">' . apply_filters('the_content', $page) . '</div>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Not beautiful, but does the job.